# Convergence of $f_n(t) = t^n - t^{2n}$ with respect to the supremum norm?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I am attempting to answer the following question:

Consider the set of functions $f \subset C[0,1].$ 
Does the function $f_n(t) = t^n - t^{2n}$ converge with respect to the supremum norm, $||.||_{\infty}$? Does it converge with respect to $ ||.||_{1}?$

This is what I have tried so far:

I think I have shown that $f_n(t)$ converges with respect to $ ||.||_{1}.$ I calculated the integral:

$\int_{0}^{1}|t^n - t^{2n}|dt$ = $\frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)} - \frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}|_{0}^{1}$ = $\frac{n}{(n+1)(2n+1)}$

which is of order $\frac{n}{n^2}$ and so converges.

It is the supremum norm I am struggling with.

$f_{n} \to f $ with respect to $||.||_{\infty}$ if $||f_{n} - f||_{\infty} \to 0$ for some $f \in C[0,1]$.

I have calculated that the supremum of the sequence of functions is constant at $f_n(t) = 0.25$ but can't see how this helps me to answer the question at hand. Is it that, since the sequence of $\sup\{|f_n(t)|:t \in [0,1]\} $ is constant, it has limit equal to that constant and thus converges? Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Look at $f_n(t)=t^n-t^{2n}=t^n(1-t^n)$. Pointwise limit is zero, then the zero function is the only candidate for the uniform limit. The function $g(t)=t^n$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, so it is always (for any $n$) going to be a point where $t^n=\frac12$. Thus
$$
\|f_n-0\|_\infty=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|t^n(1-t^n)|\ge\frac14\not\to 0\quad\text{as }n\to\infty.
$$